# Google sheets calendar with dynamic content

Tags: google-sheets

i have a google sheet with two tabs. First tab is all the reservations data i have for a house i rent (First Name, Last Name, Check in Date, Check out Date etc...) and in the second tab is a calendar. I am looking for a way, when i add a new row in the reservations tab automatically that reservation to be added in the calendar in the correct days.

This the google sheets link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oh7Pvj8G8_fnVWifiED9XS7bOCxOan8E46-Ku1UJu7s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: working with merged cells is complex; Is there any reason to do so?

Comment: I have made an example in the link in the post

Comment: see my answer, I made a copy to work on unmerged cells, add a table for monthes, and add a formula for calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, build in '`μήνας`' tab a table as

[image]

For calendar, put this function in B2 (no merged cells anymore except the title), nothing in C2, D2 ... and format as dd

```
=sequence(1;datedif((A1&"-"&vlookup(B1;'μήνας'!A:B;2;0)&"-"&1);eomonth((A1&"-"&vlookup(B1;'μήνας'!A:B;2;0)&"-"&1);0);"d")+1;(A1&"-"&vlookup(B1;'μήνας'!A:B;2;0)&"-"&1))
```

[image]

Finally, your function is in B3

```
=if(SUMPRODUCT((RESERVATIONS!$A$2:$A=$A3)*(RESERVATIONS!$D$2:$D<=B$2)*(RESERVATIONS!$F$2:$F>=B$2));"x";)
```

drag to the right and below

To retrieve the name

```
=iferror(TEXTJOIN(" ";;query(RESERVATIONS!$A:$G;"select C,B where A="&$A3&" and D<=DATE'"&TEXT(B$2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'  and F>=DATE'"&TEXT(B$2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ";0)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried it and it is very very close to what i need! i am trying now to replace the x in the calenda with the name and check in-check out time.

Comment: You will probably have to use query instaed of sumproduct

Comment: I have added a proposal to retrieve the name